# View is not showing profile when passing id parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ContactBook/profile/2

When passing id like this images in the template is not showing.

Should I need to make any changes in configuration files??

Plss help me..

```
function profile($id=0)
{
    $data['base']       = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $data['css']        = $this->config->item('css');
    $this->load->helper('url');             
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('date');        
    $this->load->model('ContactBook_Model');
    if((int)$id > 0)
         $query = $this->ContactBook_Model->get($id);
    $data['id']['value']=$query['id'];
    $data['name']['value']=$query['name'];
    $data['number']['value']=$query['number'];
    $data['img']['value']=$query['img'];
    $data['DOB']['value']=$query['DOB'];                    
    $this->load->view('ProfileContact_View',$data);

}
```

Comment: How you retrieving id from url ?

Comment: Please share the code of your index function.

Comment: profile method is added above

Comment: Is `ContactBook_Model->get($id);` function working right? If you are sure your `$id` variable has correct id, you should check to your model also. Also I guess `$data['id']['value']=$query['id'];` will be `$data['id']['value']=$query[0]['id'];` because your data maybe in first array of your `$query` variable.

Comment: There is no connection between this id and the image disappearing.I just added that img using <img src>.Th image is disappearing when the path contains any id value

Comment: I wanted to give the id part as example.  I assumed the values from database is not coming right.

Comment: values from database is coming coreclty..The image which is not showing is not from database.its just added using <img src="../../images/mobile.jpg" alt="Mobile Store" width="653" height="209" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it like this

```
$data = '';
if((int)$id > 0)
{
    $query = $this->ContactBook_Model->get($id);
    $data['id']['value']=$query[0]['id'];
    $data['name']['value']=$query[0]['name'];
    $data['number']['value']=$query[0]['number'];
    $data['img']['value']=$query[0]['img'];
    $data['DOB']['value']=$query[0]['DOB']; 
}                   
$this->load->view('ProfileContact_View',$data);
```

Comment: also check your image path given in this tag <img src="../../images/mobile.jpg" alt="Mobile Store" width="653" height="209" />

Comment: change this "../../images/mobile.jpg" to something base_url()."images/mobile.jpg" etc

Comment: can you tell me hirarchy of your image path?

Comment: if it is "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/" then your image path will be echo $base.'images/mobile.jpg';

Comment: have u checked the issue in console by firebug etc?

Comment: <img src=<?php echo $base ?>."images/mobile.jpg" alt="Mobile Store" width="653" height="209" />   Again not working

Comment: <img src=<?php echo $base."images/mobile.jpg"; ?> alt="Mobile Store" width="653" height="209" />

Comment: dont forget to accept and vote up this answer from tick and up arrow.